# Why coil at high frequency pass lower current?

Tags: mosfet, frequency, h-bridge, coil

I am currently working on a project that uses an H-bridge to output different direction current.

I use 2 P-channel MOSFETs (IRF4905), and 2 N-channel MOSFETs (IRF3710) to build my H-bridge.

*reference circuit:
https://www.homemade-circuits.com/how-to-implement-p-channel-mosfet-in-h-bridge-applications/

[image]

(The figure title is "Using P and N-channel MOSFETs", and I input signal which label as MCU)

I use an Arduino to give two different square waves between 5Hz~50Hz, 0~5V signals.

I found that the higher the frequency I give to the H-bridge, the lower current through the H-bridge (under same resistance connect to output and voltage power supply.)

Why does this will happen?

//
2021-04-22 edit
Thanks for your comments. Those really help me a lot!
Because the h-bridge output I connect to the coil(around 1000 turns)
So coil may become bigger resistance at high frequency
Could anyone give some keywords that I can do more search about this?
//
2021/7/24
Hi, Thanks all the suggestions and answers! These really help me a lot.

So after I did more research about inductor, I found that with higher frequency, the more "resistance" will occur(the actual name of this kind of resistance is inductive reactance, and the unit is ohm. )

The equation of calculating inductive reactance is 2*pi*Frequency*L
After reaching a very high frequency, the inductor will act like capacitor characteristics. This frequency is "resonance frequency"

For more detail, you can check the website: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-is-impedance.php

also: https://techweb.rohm.com/knowledge/emc/s-emc/04-s-emc/8136

Again, thanks to all of you!

Comment: Ho are you measuring the current? With a multimeter? What does its manual say about frequency response? [Edit] your question with the details and a link to the manual for your meter / scope.

Comment: Are you driving an inductive load, such as a motor or solenoid? If so, the inductance will impede higher frequency pulses more than lower frequency.

Comment: First obvious thing to do is use a oscilloscope on those gates and check if your driving circuitry behaves like you think it should.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion!  The output of h-bridge i connect to a coil. Therefore I measured the magnetic field and can see if I change the frequency, the lower magnetic field that coil generate. And also my external power supply(which is connect to the P-channel Drain) also show lower current on it.

Comment: What is the duty cycle of the PWM signal you are sending?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I do connect the output to a coil. That may be the problem. However, I have no idea why this only happen when I give 0~+5V signal, but not when I give -5~+5V signal to h-bridge

Comment: The duty cycle of square wave I used is 50%.

Comment: You want keywords? "inductance", "impedance"